# Loading data on the same form page after submitting

Tags: javascript, forms, function, addeventlistener

I have a tiny problem with this college assignment. When the user inputs their data, an account id number is created. I've worked on that and it works like it should. But here's the problem: after the user clicks the submit button and the account id number is created, what they entered needs to be displayed below it. The assignment says I need to create a function called `displayNewAccount` and put in into one of the other functions. I put in inside the `createEventListeners` function. The text needs to be displayed in a custom ID (`account`) on the HTML page. The data entered into the first name input (`fnameinput`) should display after "First Name" (`fname`) and the last name input (`lnameinput`) should display after "Last Name" (`lname`) and so on. If the `displayNewAccount` function has to be moved inside another function then that is totally fine. I've looked online and found several examples, but I couldn't get them to work for me. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

## HTML

```
<article>
 <h2>New Account Information</h2>
 <form>
  <fieldset id="deliveryinfo">
   <label>First Name</label><input type="text" id="fnameinput" name="fname">
   <label>Last Name</label><input type="text" id="lnameinput" name="lname">
   <label>Street Address</label><input type="text" id="addrinput" name="address">
   <label>City</label><input type="text" id="cityinput" name="city">
   <label>State</label><input type="text" id="stateinput" name="state">
   <label>Zip</label><input type="text" id="zipinput" name="zip">
   <label>Account ID</label><input type="text" id="accountidbox" name="accountid">
   <input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="Create Account">
  </fieldset>
  <!-- New section -->
  <fieldset>
   <div id="account">
    <!-- Data is displayed in here. -->
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </form>
</article>
```

## JavaScript

```
var newAccountObject = {};
var newAccountSubmission;

function createID() {
 var fname = document.getElementById("fnameinput");
 var lname = document.getElementById("lnameinput");
 var zip = document.getElementById("zipinput");
 var account = document.getElementById("accountidbox");
 var fields = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
 var acctid;
 var firstInit;
 var lastInit;
 if (fname !== "" || lname !== "" || zip !== "") {
  firstInit = fname.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  lastInit = lname.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
  acctid = firstInit + lastInit + zip.value;
  account.value = acctid;
  newAccountObject = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < fields.length - 1; i++) {
   newAccountObject[fields[i].name] = fields[1].value;
  }
 }
}

function createString() {
 newAccountSubmission = JSON.stringify(newAccountObject);
}

function createEventListeners() {
 var fname = document.getElementById("fnameinput");
 var lname = document.getElementById("lnameinput");
 var zip = document.getElementById("zipinput");
 if (fname.addEventListener) {
  fname.addEventListener("change", createID, false);
  lname.addEventListener("change", createID, false);
  zip.addEventListener("change", createID, false);
 }
 else if (fname.attachEvent) {
  fname.attachEvent("onchange", createID);
  lname.attachEvent("onchange", createID);
  zip.attachEvent("onchange", createID);
 }
 if (button.addEventListener) {
  button.addEventListener("click", createString, false);
 }
 else if (button.attachEvent) {
  button.attachEvent("onclick", createString);
 }


 // Displays an account summary section when the "Create Account" button is clicked.
 function displayNewAccount() {
  document.getElementById("account").innerHTML = "First Name: " + fname + "<br>" + "Last Name: " + lname + "<br>" + "Address: " + addrinput + "<br>" + "City: " + cityinput + "<br>" + "State: " + stateinput + "<br>" + "Zip: " + zipinput + "<br>" + "Account ID: " + accountidbox;
 }

 if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("click", displayNewAccount, false);
 }
 else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent("onclick", displayNewAccount);
 }


}

if (window.addEventListener) {
 window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
 window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
}
```

Comment: If i run your code i have an error in console: 'if (button.addEventListener)' button is not defined. Can you provide a JSFiddle working env?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work on JSFiddle, but here it is https://jsfiddle.net/hp6wx0xn/1/.

Comment: JSFiddle ok but the error persist. The button in not defined in line 43-44-46-47 (Javascript panel). With this errors the function called createEventListeners doesn't bind the click listener.